# Base URL not working in Keycloak email template

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak templates to send an email. I am using `${client.baseUrl}` where I want to use the baseUrl to redirect to another link, but Keycloak is saying that it doesn't exist. It's working fine in login template.